# DataFrame columns to dictionary with multiple keys and values

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'From':['a','b','c','d'],
    'To':['h','m','f','f'],
    'week':[1,2,3,3]
})
```

[image]

I want to use column 'To' and 'week' as keys to map to value 'From', create a dictionary like `{(1,'h'):'a',(2,'m'):'b',(3,'f'):['c','d']}`, is there a way to do this?  I tried to use

```
dict(zip([tuple(x) for x in df[['week','To']].to_numpy()], df['From']))
```

but it only gives me `{(1,'h'):'a',(2,'m'):'b',(3,'f'):'d'}`

. If there are multiple 'From's for the same ('week', 'To'), I want to put it in a list or set. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.groupby()` method followed by an `.apply(list)` method on the column `From` to convert the results into a list. From here, pandas has a `.to_dict()` method to convert your results to a dictionary.

```
>>> df.groupby(['To', 'week'])['From'].apply(list).to_dict()
{('f', 3): ['c', 'd'], ('h', 1): ['a'], ('m', 2): ['b']}
>>>
>>> # use lambda to convert lists with only one value to string
>>> df.groupby(['To', 'week'])['From'].apply(lambda x: list(x) if len(x) > 1 else list(x)[0]).to_dict()
{('f', 3): ['c', 'd'], ('h', 1): 'a', ('m', 2): 'b'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get your desired dictionary:

```
df.groupby(['To','week'])['From'].agg(','.join).apply(lambda s: s.split(',') if ',' in s else s).to_dict()
```

**Output**:

```
>>> df.groupby(['To','week'])['From'].agg(','.join).apply(lambda s: s.split(',') if ',' in s else s).to_dict()
{('f', 3): ['c', 'd'], ('h', 1): 'a', ('m', 2): 'b'}
```

`groupby` on `To,Week` and `join` the values with `,`. Then just use `apply` to convert `,` separated values into lists, and finally convert the result to dictionary.